# Retrieve zentralblatt (zbMATH) bib reference from script

Tags: bibtex, scripts

I want to start using scrips to organize my bibtex file and I would love to use zbMATH's database for that.

I already know how to create an URL to search for a paper by fields, such as in:

```
https://zbmath.org/?q=au:john+ti:surface
```

This returns me a webpage (html) with the correct search results. But how do I specify that I want the results in BibTeX? Actually on the html there is a button to get to the bib-file I want, but I can't get it through the URL...

PS: sorry for the scripting question in TeX Exchange, but it's BibTeX, so I don't know the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote a tool just for this:  http://ctan.org/pkg/crossrefware has `bibzbladd.pl: add Zbl num­bers to pa­pers in a given bib file`

You may want to try it.

Comment: Is it possible to download bib files from zbmath using your package?

Comment: no, right now it just checks zbl number